# JavaScript Masonry combined with ImagesLoaded is not initialized

Tags: javascript, masonry, imagesloaded

everybody!

I'm building my first website from scratch. I know HTML and CSS, but my knowledge of JavaScript and PHP is really basic. So, for the website I'm using Masonry grid layout library combined it with ImagesLoaded, so that images don't overlap. I've included a script in my HTML according to the instruction on the official webpage, but somehow it's not working at all. (Just Masonry, without ImagesLoaded, was working, but images were overlapping.) Please, tell me, what am I doing wrong.

Here is the webpage. As you see, Masonry was not initialized.

http://vprilenska.netai.net/design_archandfilm.php

Here is the script. I've included it at the bottom of my HTML before body closing tag.

```
<script src='js/masonry.js'></script>
<script src='js/imagesloaded.js'></script>
<script>
    var container = document.querySelector('#masonry');
    var msnry;
    // initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
    imagesLoaded( container, function() {
        msnry = new Masonry( container, {
        gutter: container.querySelector('.gut_width'),
        itemSelector: '.item',
        stamp: '.stamp',
        columnWidth: container.querySelector('.col_width');
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Yes, Masonry is applied to items. Each item is a div with an image and a caption, floated to the right. All images are located in the container masonry. Column width and gutter is defined by elements.

Comment: have you tried doing this inside a document ready event ?

Comment: I've tried Masonry inside window.onload event, it was working ok. But I'd like to try ImagesLoaded as well, as the official webpage suggests. Besides, I'd like to use JavaScript solution, not jQuery.

Comment: when you put your code inside a document ready function the code will run after all the elements have been loaded. You may be trying to arrange images before they are completely loaded. try this 

$( document ).ready(function() {
  // put your old code here
});

Comment: also masonry has a doc ready https://github.com/desandro/doc-ready

Comment: @astro Putting the script just before `</body>` like the OP explicitly states they did has the same effect

Comment: certain browsers behave differently when doing that. its always better to use document ready.

Comment: @astro What is the point of using ImagesLoaded then? As I said, Masonry was working ok with window.onload. As I understand it's a JavaScript alternative of jQuery $(document).ready(). I want to understand, why ImagesLoaded does not work. It is just that ImagesLoaded has other additional functions that I may use in case it works. So, it's better.

Comment: to help you make a plunker and post here.

Comment: @astro I think a problem is in the way I'm initializing Masonry with ImagesLoaded, in the code above. The website was working with just Masonry, but the images were overlapping because they were not completely loaded.

Comment: That is what im saying. If the doc ready doesn't work. try refreshing the masonry in setTimeout with a small value.

Answer (score 0):

The script was not working because there was an unexpected ';' in the following line:

```
columnWidth: container.querySelector('.col_width')
```